# Android date formatting

Tags: java, android, date

I am trying to change the format of dates retrieved from a database but struggling, I only have the relevant code below.

I have a `dateStr` that is a String and the current format is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss (2013-12-01 13:12:02)`, what I am trying to get is `dd MMM yy, HH:mm (1 Dec 13, 13:12)`.

What I have tried is the following:

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date(dateStr);
        String date_format = sdf.format(date);
```

The above doesn't work, I have tried other methods as well from other users asking similar questions but usually just returns just the formatting string

Also, the above method tells me that the "The constructor Date(String) is deprecated" so wondering if there is a better method

here is the complete Code:

```
    public void updateData(MessageInfo[] messages, FriendInfo[] friends,
        FriendInfo[] unApprovedFriends, String userKey) {
    this.setUserKey(userKey);
    // FriendController.
    MessageController.setMessagesInfo(messages);
    // Log.i("MESSAGEIMSERVICE","messages.length="+messages.length);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < messages.length) {

        //TODO this problem needs a fix
        String dateStr = messages[i].sentdt; 


        messageReceived(messages[i].userid, messages[i].messagetext, dateStr);
        i++;
    }

    FriendController.setFriendsInfo(friends);
    FriendController.setUnapprovedFriendsInfo(unApprovedFriends);
}
```

Comment: What are you passing as `dateStr`?

Comment: The date from the DB, it's a string in the following format: 2013-12-01 13:12:02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss");
            Date d;
            try {
                d = fmt.parse(st);
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat prnt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
            String newDate=prnt.format(d)
```

Comment: I have tried this before, but if I do it this way then the app doesn't retrieve the messages for some reason.

Comment: This seemed to work for me. It turnes out my main problem was using "kk" as a 24hour format, instead changed that to "HH" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better way. Obtain the date from the data base as a `Date` instead of as a string and you don't have to parse it.

```
java.sql.Date date = resultSet.getDate("column name");
String date_format = sdf.format(date);
```

The `Date(String)` constructor only parses strings in [the documented format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to work, the app queries a php server and then returns data as XML that I assume always gets seen as a string?

Comment: So your app actually queries a web service, not a database. Can you not change `MessageInfo` so that it returns the date as a date instead of as a string?

Comment: I did change it everywhere in my code, but in my XML handler it gave me warnings saying that I cannot fetch a string as a date.

Answer (score 0):

You need **two** `SimpleDateFormat`s. One for parsing String to date (using `"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"` template)

And another one for formatting date to the expected String (using `"dd MMM yy, HH:mm:ss"`), similar to what you've already did.

```
SimpleDateFormat inputSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
Date date = inputSdf.parse(dateStr);
SimpleDateFormat outputSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm:ss");
String date_format = sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String dateString = "03/26/2012 11:49:00 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

see this format this is use full

[Date and Time Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and

this

[Date and Time format](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)